# Paperclip: How to store a picture in a Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, console, paperclip

I tried storing a local image in a rails console.

Because I have many pictures in my local storage (I use crawler to download tons of pictures), I want to store them into a database, with the benefit of paperclip to do some image job, like thumbnail etc.
If I use a webpage to save new pictures to database one by one, it will cost a lot of time. So I want to find a way in rails console (some code) that can batch save-picture-into-database.

Comment: I recommend taking more time with your question, including what you've tried and why you want to use "console" to store a local image... you'll get a higher chance of a reply by taking more time yourself.

Answer (score 56):

To further clarify @andrea's answer:

`YourPaperclippedModelHere.new(:your_paperclip_field => File.new(path, "r"))`

So if your model is called Image and your paperclip field is data:

`Image.new(:data => File.new(path_to_your_file, "r"))`

Answer (score 19):

If this is the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar
end
```

then the following should work from the console:

```
>> User.create(:avatar => File.open('/path/to/image.jpg', 'rb'))
```

Comment: For those that are curious, `'rb'` and `'r'` in the `File.open` parameter are interchangable, as per: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7085623/293280

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if it is what you want ... but
to save an paperclip asset from console
You could simple use a File instance .
a.e.

```
Image.new :data=>File.new("/path/to/image.jpg","r")
```

Comment: ruby-1.9.2-p0 > Image.new
NameError: uninitialized constant Image
 from (irb):2
 from /home/mlzboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
 from /home/mlzboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
 from /home/mlzboy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
 from script/rails:6:in `require'
 from script/rails:6:in `<main>'

Comment: i tried use Image.new in rails console but it raise errors like above

Comment: In this case the File.new doesn't work, instead you shoult try this

`Image.create(:data => File.open('/path/to/image.jpg', 'r'))`

Comment: For future readers:  `Image` is not built into Ruby or Rails; it is a model which would have to be defined just like `User` or `Post` in the app.  `Image` here is being used as an example of an ActiveRecord model.

Answer (score 2):

Late Answer but hopefully it will work for others.
You need to include.

`File.new("#{Rails.root}/public/images/default_avatar.png", "r")`