# Insert text into existing file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a txt file.how can I place some text among that and don't overwrite it? because when I use for example f.puts "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" Ruby overwrites my txt file .
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking how to *insert* text into the middle of an existing file, as below, you can't:

```
Original file first half, Original File second half
```

becomes:

```
Original file first half, Inserted text, Original File second half
```

You need to make a new file, copy the first half of the original into it, then write the new text, then copy the rest of the original file.

Answer (score 18):

You need to open it in append mode

```
File.open("file.txt", "a+"){|f| f << "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" }
```

Check out your previous question

[File opening mode in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085595/file-openning-mode-in-ruby)

Comment: More correctly, that would be the append mode, rather than write mode.  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html

Comment: @Ryanmt he needs to append text not to overwrite it, as I understand

Comment: Agreed, that is his purpose, but your answer had said 'right mode' which wasn't exactly correct, so I thought I'd clarify.

Answer (score 4):

You've got to set the mode for the file when using open on a file.

There are more details here : http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000889