# How do I automate running a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have written a ruby script (code below) to scrape from Deliveroo.co.uk.

Right now I run it manually by going to terminal and typing in 'ruby ....rb'.

How do I automate things so that this script runs automatically every hour?
Also, how do I save the output from each run without overwriting the previous output?

Code is below.. thank you.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

# Store URL to be scraped
url = "https://deliveroo.co.uk/restaurants/london/maida-vale?postcode=W92DE"

# Parse the page with Nokogiri
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

# Display output onto the screen
name =[]
page.css('span.list-item-title.restaurant-name').each do |line|
  name << line.text.strip
end

category = []
page.css('span.restaurant-detail.detail-cat').each do |line|
  category << line.text.strip
end

delivery_time = []
page.css('span.restaurant-detail.detail-time').each do |line|
  delivery_time << line.text.strip
end

distance = []
page.css('span.restaurant-detail.detail-distance').each do |line|
  distance << line.text.strip
end

status = []
page.css('li.restaurant--details').each do |line|
  if line.attr("class").include? "unavailable"
    sts = "closed"
  else
    sts = "open"
  end
  status << sts
end

# Write data to CSV file
CSV.open("deliveroo.csv", "w") do |file|
file << ["Name", "Category", "Delivery Time", "Distance", "Status"]
  name.length.times do |i|
      file << [name[i], category[i], delivery_time[i], distance[i], status[i]]
  end
end
```

Comment: What operating system do you use? Linux, Windows...

Comment: [scheduling libs/modules for Ruby](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/scheduling)

Comment: For Linux: Add `#! /usr/bin/env ruby` at the top and mention it in the crontab.

Comment: Good point @knut I just assumend hikmatyar was using linux :)

Answer (score 5):

There's two questions, I'll try to answer them below.

**How to run periodically:** 
What you are looking for is a cronjob, there are many resources out there for creating one.

Look into `cron` or gems like `whenever` / `clockwork`.

**Save output between multiple runs:** In order to save the output you could just write to a file directly in ruby, very similar to what you are doing right now.

The way you're saving it right now is:

```
CSV.open("deliveroo.csv", "w") do |file|
```

The `"w"` opens the file and overwrites any content present in it, try `"a"` (append) instead.

```
CSV.open("deliveroo.csv", "a") do |file|
```

Read more here about opening files in different modes: [File opening mode in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085595/file-opening-mode-in-ruby)