# simplecov-rcov is throwing a Encoding::UndefinedConversionError

Tags: rspec-rails, simplecov, rcov

I have the following setup

**Gemfile**

```
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
  gem 'simplecov-rcov', require: false
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::RcovFormatter
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
```

In the specs I have tests for views.

After the tests are run and rcov tries to save the rcov_result I receive the following error:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/simplecov-rcov-0.2.3/lib/simplecov-rcov.rb:52:in `write': "\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: What version of ruby/ rails are you using?

Comment: ruby 2.5.1, rails 5.1.5

Comment: I had similar issue and the code I posted as answer fixed mine. Did you try that?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I don't have access to that project anymore.

Comment: That's alright. Someone else might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Update the simplecov and simplecov-rcov gems to the latest versions and place the following code in your test/spec-helpers:

```
   class SimpleCov::Formatter::RcovFormatter
     def write_file(template, output_filename, binding)
       rcov_result = template.result( binding )
       File.open( output_filename, 'wb' ) do |file_result|
         file_result.write rcov_result
       end
     end
   end
```

More information here on files modes: [File opening mode in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085595/file-opening-mode-in-ruby)